# Vicon motion capturing: which ROS package is the best

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

we're planning on using a Vicon motion capturing system and want to use one of the available ROS packages to interface it. Using the ROS wiki, I already found 3 different implementations:

- http://www.ros.org/wiki/vicon_bridge
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/vicon_mocap
- http://www.ros.org/wiki/vicon

Is this list complete or are there other implementations which I didn't find?
Is there any reason for me to choose one of those in particular? Are they all offering the same interfacing?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11456/vicon-motion-capturing:-which-ros-package-is-the-best/) by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2011-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Obviously http://www.ros.org/wiki/vicon, we wrote it! :P

I think they are all equivalent, as the functionalities the VICON API provides are very simple. Probably the other two packages are better documented, so it might be easier to start with them.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2011-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) on 2011-10-19**:
Got it working easily using the vicon_bridge package - thanks

**Comment by [Oscar](https://answers.ros.org/users/5722/oscar/) on 2013-08-02**:
What i have access to is the vicon nexus software which im not at all familiar with. To use vicon bridge to get data of couple of robots, do i need to setup anything in vicon nexus? . And do i need to specify each robot as segments or subjects in the nexus software. Thanks in advance

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2014-03-26**:
what is wrong? it is gone!

**Comment by [101010](https://answers.ros.org/users/3108/101010/) on 2015-01-08**:
Yes, it is gone. Unfortunate. Does anyone know of a good Vicon ROS node that has been catkin'nized?

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2015-01-22**:
check out https://github.com/kartikmohta/vicon

**Comment by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) on 2017-11-26**:
So https://github.com/kartikmohta/vicon is down, are there any other suggestions or up-to-date packages?